# Support of a probability measure vs support of its margins

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on the product of two metric spaces $(X, d) $ and $(Y, h) $. Assume its marginal probability measures $\mu_X$ on $X $ and  $\mu_Y$ on $Y$ have compact supports. Can we conclude that $\mu$ is compactly supported as well?

Comment: Do you mean their product as a topological space with the product topology? Or their product as a metric space, in which case I'm wondering what the metric on the product space is. (Maybe it doesn't matter....) $\qquad$

Comment: I'd start by thinking about whether the support of $\mu$ is a subset of the product of the supports of the marginals.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking to endow the product space with the product topology and the Borel $\sigma$-field induced by the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ is a member of the support of $\mu.$ Then every open neighborhood of $(x,y)$ has positive $\mu$-measure. For any open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ within $X,$ the set $U\times Y$ is an open neighborhood of $(x,y)$ within $X\times Y.$ Thus $\mu(U\times Y)>0.$ Thus the marginal assigns positive measure to $U.$ So every open neighborhood of $x$ is given positive probability by the marginal. Since $U$ was an arbitrary open neighborhood of $x,$ it follows that $x$ is a member of the support of the marginal.

Thus if $(x,y)$ is a member of the support of $\mu,$ then $x$ is a member of the support of the marginal, and similarly $y$ is a member of the support of the other marginal.

Hence $(x,y)$ is a member of the product of the supports of the marginals.

So the support of $\mu$ is a subset of the product of the supports of the marginals.

The support of any probability distribution is closed. So the support of $\mu$ is a closed subset of the aforementioned product, and the product is compact.

Comment: Therefore we deduce that if, e.g., $(X, d) $ and $(Y, h) $ are Euclidean subspaces, the support of $\mu$ is closed and contained in a bounded set (i.e. the product of the supports of the marginal probability measures) and is therefore bounded itself, hence compact. But, in general, we cannot claim this, correct?

Comment: @JackLondon : No: closed and bounded is not enough to imply compact in metric spaces in general. In Euclidean spaces all closed and bounded sets are compact, but in some metric spaces some closed and bounded sets are not compact. For example in $\ell^2,$ which is the set of all sequences $(z_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of complex numbers for which $\sum_n \left|z_n\right|^2<+\infty,$ the set of sequences in which all but one component are $0$ and that one is $1$ is closed and bounded but not compact. However, in all metric spaces, all closed subsets of a compact set are compact. $\qquad$

Comment: @JackLondon : $\qquad\uparrow\qquad$Maybe it's best to start with the last sentence in the comment above. $\qquad$

Comment: @JackLondon : In all metric spaces, every closed subset of a compact set is compact. $\qquad$

Comment: @JackLondon : Theorem: Closed subsets of compact sets are compact. Proof: Let $F$ be a closed subset of a compact set $K$ in a topological space $X.$ Let $\mathcal C$ be an open cover of $F.$ then $\mathcal C \cup \{X\smallsetminus F\}$ is an open cover of $K.$ It has a finite subcover $\{C_1,\ldots,C_k\} \cup (X\smallsetminus K).$ (If it can be covered by $\{C_1,\ldots,C_k\}$ alone then it can be covered by $\{C_1,\ldots,C_k\} \cup (X\smallsetminus K),$ so that is a finite subcover.) Finally $\{C_1,\ldots,C_k\}$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal C$ that covers $F. \qquad$